# Connecting multiple voltage sensors with the STM32 Nucleo board

Tags: sensor, stm32, i2c, voltage-measurement

I want to connect multiple voltage sensors to the nucleo board. Lets say 4 voltage sensors of same kind with same address. So, I thought I could connect all the 4 sensors with the nucleo board with the help of I2C communication protocol.

Is this possible?

If possible I had a doubt that all the 4 voltage sensors will be having same addresses. But I want to call all the fours sensors at a time. How can I do this.

Please any help.

Comment: Please provide document. what do you mean by voltage sensor? which nucleo board?

Comment: I have not decided any voltage sensor yet. But I need to buy it in few days. The nucleo board is STM32 NUCLEO-F070RB.

Comment: NUCLEO-F070RB has two I2C line(i2c1, i2c2). you can use them to read exact same addresses. as you mentioned you haven't decided which sensor you want to use yet so you should consider some of the chips has i2c address pins. this pins changes the i2c address according to pull-up or pull-down states. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/5096/how-to-resolve-i2c-address-clashes?rq=1 here is an another question about your problem.

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge, you cannot have same address for all the slaves on I2C bus especially if you want to read them one by one.

If you want to do so, i suggest that you have an i2C multiplexer something like [this](https://www.adafruit.com/product/2717?gclid=CjwKCAiAqvXTBRBuEiwAE54dcI4PUu2gIZucE6UwH3ENLv7pEfEC4nvW5yARR5bT8S0VnBBkJMj78RoCwm0QAvD_BwE) as well in your circuitry.

Using it is fairly straight-forward: the multiplexer itself is on I2C address 0x70 (but can be adjusted from 0x70 to 0x77) and you simply write a single byte with the desired multiplexed output number to that port, and bam - any future I2C packets will get sent to that port. In theory, you could have 8 of these multiplexers on each of 0x70-0x77 addresses in order to control 64 of the same-I2C-addressed-part.